# Can't create new tenant admin in kaa 0.10.0

Tags: kaa

I am trying the new version of Kaa 0.10.0 and I am trying to create a new admin user to the tenant I have created, so I set the outgoing email settings and then go to add tenant admin user but I never got email to the specified email although I use the exact same configurations in kaa 0.9.0 and it's working fine?? is this a bug?

Comment: How did you create an user account? Via REST API or Administration UI?

Comment: Administration UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below configurations. If this doesn't work, check System LOG and post error message.

```
SMTP Protocol: SMTP
SMTP Host:smtp.gmail.com
SMTP Port: 587
TLS : (check)
Username: (your gmail username)
Password: (your gmail password)
```

Here is the link of gmail smtp [Gmail SMTP Settings](https://www.wpsitecare.com/gmail-smtp-settings/)

Comment: I will give it a try, and get back to you

Comment: Thanks so much, It worked sorry for my late response