# Why is my Kaaproject unable to send an email request for tenants?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, smtp-auth, server-error, kaa

My Kaaproject Cloud service deployed over MS Azure is unable to send any email request, which is shunning me from creating tenants.

My Outgoing SMTP mail server details are:

> From Address: admin@kaaproject.org
>
> SMTP Protocol: SMTP
>
> SMTP Host:
>
> SMTP Port: 25
>
> SMTP Timeout: 10000
>
> Username: New Username
>
> Password: New Password

Whenever I try to create a user under Tenant, it provides me with this error:

## Unexpected service error occurred: Failed to send email with temporary password. Please, check outgoing email settings. See server logs for details.

Comment: try this out, I had this problem before check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366205/cant-create-new-tenant-admin-in-kaa-0-10-0

Answer (score 0):

Check your [outgoing mail settings](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Getting-started/#configuring-outgoing-mail-settings). Also, investigate Kaa server logs for more details. See [troubleshooting guide](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Administration-guide/Troubleshooting/).